# jquery accordion menu - link problem

Tags: jquery, html, menu, href

I'm using this http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/ accordion menu.

Problem is, is that the main-menu links only work to expand the sub-menu, but don't
function as links themselves. I want the main-menu links to go to the link and (i set the expand class via a php script) unfold the sub-menu.

Here's the code:

html (example):

```
<span class="acc_menu"> 
<ul class="menu"> 
<li class="expand"> 
<a href="/a_page.html">A page</a> 
<ul class="menu nestedmenu acitem"> 
<li><a href="/other_page.html">Other page</a></li> 
<li><a href="/other_page2.html">Other page 2</a></li> 
<li><a href="/other_page3.html">Other page 3</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {
return this.each(function(){
    var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
    $('.acitem', this).hide();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active');
    $('li a', this).click(
        function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var theElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
                    window.location.href = this.href;
                }
                $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    }    
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                    if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                        $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', 
                        function() {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                        }
                    );
                    return false;  
                }
                return false;
            }
            if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
                $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                });
                theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                    $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
);
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').initMenu();
}); // enter code here
```

Comment: Did I understand this correctly? You want the top level links to work like actual links and reveal the sub level menu?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly :o)

Comment: Do you want the url to be opened in an element on the current page? Or for the link to open a new page entirely?

Comment: Go to the page specified, like a normal link would work, but no inline stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `target="_blank"` to your parent link, and remove the `return false;`

Comment: No complete new page, The href's are fine the way they are :o) The problem is in the Jquery stuff. Which "return false" do you mean? I count 4. The top one?

Comment: @okdan: if you  want to follow the link, then you can remove all the `return false;` but then, what is the use of your jQuery plugin?!

Comment: @ifaour, yes, complety true, but this is what my client asked for. The expantion is the only useful. I looked for css only solutions for unfolding a UL, but all of them use javascript ie jquery in some way, and since i already wrote a php script which expands the appropriate sub-menu for the given page, I want to stick with this script :o) I dont have much time left :o)

Comment: Im definately gonna delve into this jquery stuff as soon as im done with this, one of my weaker coding skills. And ive been out of the running for 4 years. *Cough*.

Comment: @okdan: lol, then you do what you have to do man! you've been out of the running for 4 years, and I've been out of the freelancing business for years! and you are welcome ;-)